# Incremental builds Netlify + Gatsby not working

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I have been trying to setup Gatsby + Netlify with incremental builds but I cannot get it to work. Gatsby always thinks that every page needs to be updated. Does anyone know what I can do?

Look in the log. I use Gatsby cache but it updates pages that I haven't touched.

```html
 PM: ​
12:08:07 PM: ❯ Loading plugins
12:08:07 PM:    - netlify-plugin-gatsby-cache@0.2.2 from netlify.toml and package.json
12:08:08 PM: ​
12:08:08 PM: ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
12:08:08 PM: │ 1. onPreBuild command from netlify-plugin-gatsby-cache │
12:08:08 PM: └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
12:08:08 PM: ​
12:08:11 PM: Found a Gatsby cache. We’re about to go FAST. ⚡️
12:08:11 PM: ​
12:08:11 PM: (netlify-plugin-gatsby-cache onPreBuild completed in 3.2s)
12:08:11 PM: ​
12:08:11 PM: ┌────────────────────────────────────┐
12:08:11 PM: │ 2. build.command from netlify.toml │
12:08:11 PM: └────────────────────────────────────┘
12:08:11 PM: ​
12:08:11 PM: $ npm run build
12:08:11 PM: > gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 build /opt/build/repo
12:08:11 PM: > GATSBY_EXPERIMENTAL_PAGE_BUILD_ON_DATA_CHANGES=true gatsby build --log-pages
12:08:14 PM: success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.063s
12:08:18 PM: success load plugins - 4.496s
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/helse-bemanning/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/helse-bemanning/lon/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/helse-bemanning/recensioner/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/helse-bemanning/jobb/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/annsam/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/annsam/lon/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/annsam/recensioner/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/annsam/jobb/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/medicarrera/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/medicarrera/lon/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/medicarrera/recensioner/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/medicarrera/jobb/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/coliva/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/coliva/lon/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/coliva/recensioner/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/coliva/jobb/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/vacant/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/vacant/lon/
12:10:15 PM: Updated page: /companies/vacant/recensioner/
```

Answer (score 1):

## 2022 Update

`netlify-plugin-gatsby-cache` has been bundled inside [`netlify-plugin-gatsby`](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-plugin-gatsby#readme), along with further features, so the new configuration should be approached as:

```
  [[plugins]]
  package = "@netlify/plugin-gatsby"
```

---

In your root project folder, create a file named `netlify.toml` with the following content:

```
[[plugins]]
    package = "netlify-plugin-gatsby-cache"
```

Then, in Netlify install the plugin:
[image: Netlify plugin page]

That's it. You don't need to set any command or so, Gatsby + Netlify will do the rest. Your next deploy:

```
9:49:34 PM: ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
9:49:34 PM: │ 1. onPreBuild command from netlify-plugin-gatsby-cache │
9:49:34 PM: └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
9:49:34 PM: ​
9:49:36 PM: Found a Gatsby cache. We’re about to go FAST. ⚡️
9:49:36 PM: ​
9:49:36 PM: (netlify-plugin-gatsby-cache onPreBuild completed in 1.7s)
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or the code of your Netlify deploy log?

Comment: I posted an excerpt from my logs - thanks for the help.

Comment: Indeed you are using the incremental build but it compiles again all your files. Do you run any `gatsby clean` or similar?

Comment: Yes I have done that. I believe it's something with Netlify but I don't understand what it is.

Comment: If you retry another deploy just when the previous one finished, is it still enqueuing all those files?

Comment: No - then it's working well! Do you have any ideas on what it can be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217561/discussion-between-alfred-wahlforss-and-ferran-buireu).